# Syncing communications between Pidgin clients

Tags: pidgin, xmpp, sms

Is there a way to sync communications between multiple pidgin clients? We have SMS texts that come to 8 clients, but if one of the office desk clients responds, no one else in the office see's the text that gets sent out, leaving the conversation in the dark for others.

The protocol being used is XMPP.

Comment: This might help https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/141087-two-openfire-clients-with-same-user-id-can-i-get-a-message-to-both-at-once -- it all depends on what server software is running the network.